# Why can't I comment?

Tags: support, comments, reputation, privileges

I'm pretty new to the SX world and slightly confused. I can comment on my own question and everything in that page, but the "add comment" button and textboxes just don't appear in any other page. It seems though that I can edit and answer in any page. Do I need to gather more reputation in order to comment?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need a [reputation of 50](https://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment) for unconfined commenting. See the [privileges](https://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges) page for other thresholds.