# Why can a new user post an answer but not a comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, reputation, new-users, privileges

We can read [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2692/14757) that there is a minimal reputation to comment a post. But there is no minimal to post an answer!

I believe that an answer is more important than a comment.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12119/lower-the-amount-of-reputation-needed-to-comment

Comment: I suppose: New users can leave comments on their question and all its answers even with 1 rep

Comment: My guess: Because an answer _Only_ can bring the post to front roll screen, thereby corrected/flagged/monitored easily by community to earn more rep to reach 50 barrier. Basically New-users are encouraged to show off their skills to reach 50 rep barrier to comment

Answer (score 9):

I admittedly have no idea why this actually is the case, but my guess would be that the reasoning might have gone something like the following:

commenting is perhaps more conducive to spam than is answering, and so we might want a user to demonstrate that they really intend to be part of the community before allowing them to comment wherever they please. Of course, hypothetically speaking, answers are equally good places to post spam (or irrelevant information that detracts from the purpose of the site). I would presume that the fact that answers can be downvoted and have an impact on reputation ([and, in certain cases, the user's actual account privileges](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/answer-bans)) is, at least theoretically, a preventative measure.

Of course, this is just speculation on my part. It's an interesting question.

Comment: High rep users can enforce deletion of questions pretty fast but they have to wait for the mod or even powers-that-be to handle the comment flags (guessing)

Comment: @percusse: High rep users can _edit_ questions without problems; but editing _comments_ is left to the mods.